# Why does this Perl function appear to process only some of its arguments?

Tags: perl, arguments, argument-passing

Why do

```
my $i=0;
my @arr=();

sub readall {
    foreach (@_) {
        $arr[$i] = shift @_;
        $i++;
    }
}

readall(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
print "@arr"
```

and

```
my $i=0;
my @arr=();

sub readall {
    foreach (@_) {
        $arr[$i] = shift @_;
        print $arr[$i];
        $i++;
    }
}

readall(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

print only three of the arguments to `readall`?

Why does this function, which seems like it should behave the same, process all five arguments?

```
sub readall {
    foreach (@_) {
        print $_;
    }
}

readall(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

This also reads all five (but does operate on a different principle):

```
my @arr=();

sub readall {
    push(@arr, @_);
}

readall(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
print "@arr"
```

Comment: Your posts would be much easier to read if you posted proper scripts rather than 100char long one-liners. You'd also get syntax highlighting if you used a proper editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you shift your array, it gets shorter... So you are not operating on the whole array, and it will stop early. You can see this by adding a line to your code:

```
perl -wlae 'my $i=0; my @arr=(); sub readall {foreach (@_) {$arr[$i]=shift @_; $i++; print @_;}} readall(1,2,3,4,5); print "@arr"'

2345
345
45
```

I assume you can figure it out from here.

Comment: note that modifying (adding or removing elements) the array you are looping over is explicitly not supported.  if you wish to do so, loop over indexes instead: `for (my $index = 0; $index < @array; ++$index ) {  }`

Answer (score 6):

Using `foreach` and `shift` on the same array may be causing confusion. Both the ones that fail use it, both that dont.. dont.

Just changing `shift @_` to `$_` fixes it.

This is happening because you are shortening the array as you are iterating.

Answer (score 4):

You iterate over all arguments in `@_`, simultaneously shifting `@_` to make it shorter:

`sub readall {foreach (@_) {$arr[$i]=shift @_ ....}`

Let great perlists here explain what's expected in this case, what's documented and why you shouldn't do it. For me it's just logically wrong, and does not make any sense. Perhaps `s/foreach/while/` is more idiomatic (at least, it works).

Answer (score 4):

`shift @_` inside of `foreach (@_)` is wrong, getting rid of it fixes the array walk:

```
$ perl -wlae 'my $i=0; my @arr=(); sub readall {foreach (@_) {$arr[$i]=$_[$i]; $i++}} readall(1,2,3,4,5); print "@arr"'
1 2 3 4 5
```

`foreach` works referencing `$_` to each element of the array:

```
$ perl -wlae 'my @arr=(1..5);foreach (@arr) { $_ *= 2 }; foreach (@arr) { print }'
2
4
6
8
10
```

So dereferencing an element with an `unshift`/`pop` messes everything.